# Load testing Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, jmeter, load-testing

We wanted to perform load testing of a silverlight application. We only need to test for max of 50-75 users 
Wanted to get inputs if we can use JMeter and if yes, how can we go about it.Also, please do suggest if there are any other possible alternatives and cost associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load test Silverlight application with regular HTTP samplers as the protocol is binary and needs to be decoded before being able to:

- variabilize
- correlate

In order to do so, you would need to develop a plugin for this technology which might not be easy.

Some interesting elements:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler

Alternatively, you could have a look at other solutions.

Comment: Thanks. By any chance are you aware of any other tool which can be used for testing silverlight application.

Comment: Ok. But, the provided response unfortunately does not give answer I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe, but what if it's the correct one :) ? And I am afraid it is the correct one. but I'll happily be wrong. Just check top answerers on jmeter tag and our profile to see if we are serious or not.

Comment: Any tool which supports the communications protocol of Silverlight applications, HTTP, can be used to performance test the back end infrastructure associated with Silverlight applications.  In short, pretty much every single performance testing tool on the market today for testing applications, GNU or Commercially licensed, can be used to performance test the infrastructure for Silverlight apps.   Each has a different labor quotient to achieved a desired output, but that is a topic for another thread

Comment: Hi James, Do you consider that load testing a Silverlight application without any correlation would be an acceptable load test ? That was the main point of my answer. I tend to think it is not, that's why I was highlighting such point

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight runs on client side therefore I don't see a lot of sense in load testing it as it will always have only one user.

If your Silverlight application assumes a backend and you need to know if the backend is capable of handling 50-70 concurrent users - you could use JMeter for this. In the absolute majority of cases Silverlight applications use [SOAP web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) for communication between client application and the backend and SOAP is something JMeter naturally supports via its [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, check out [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) User Manual chapter for more details.

Alternative options are in:

1. If your Silverlight application functions are exposed to JavaScript you could use JMeter's [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) to kick off real browsers, invoked functions methods and render the results.
2. Alternative to JMeter would be HP LoadRunner [which seems to support Silverlight up to certain extent](https://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/146500_c_silverlight_overview.htm) (not more than JMeter doesn however) and is free up to 50 concurrent users.